# Where did I go wrong in solving $y' + 2y = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

to solve this I first solve the characteristic equation $r+2=0$ and since $r = -2$ I have $y_{1} = e^{-2x}$. Then I get a particular solution $y_{p} = C$ because number on the right side is just a constant 1 (what is this "number on the right side" called?)

plugging $y_{p}=C$ into the original equation I get $2C = 1$ and $C=\frac{1}{2}$. So my solution to this question is $y_{c}=\frac{1}{2} + e^{-2x}$. However the correct answer is $y_{c}=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} e^{-2x}$. What did I do wrongly?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $y_1 = ke^{-2x}$?  Also, do you have an initial value?  If not then an arbitrary constant will remain in your answer.

Comment: As suggested, were you also given the constraint $y(0) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that was a constraint I missed out. how do I use that constraint in getting k = $-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: See the answer @kipf gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complementary function (or general solution, or what you have called $y_1$) is $y_1 = Ae^{-2x}$. You can't determine this constant unless you have a boundary condition. So actually, the correct answer is $y_c = \frac 12 + A e^{-2x}$, where $A$ is an arbitrary constant that can be determined by a boundary condition. In this case, you should have some extra information that lets you determine $A = -\frac 12$.

---

We know $y = \frac 12 + Ae^{-2x}$ and $y(0) = 0$. Substituting $x=0$ and $y=0$, we have $0 = \frac 12 + A e^{-2(0)} = \frac 12 + A$, so $A = - \frac 12$. Thus, $y = \frac 12 - \frac 12 e^{-2x}$ as expected.

Comment: Missed out a constraint $y(0) = 0$. How can I use that to determine A?

Comment: @lin0258 See new part.